# Javascript not working when imported into html from js file?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some code in a .js file that is used in checkboxes. When imported into the html, though, the first two checkbox sections work (location, pop) but the last one does not. When I have the js in the html instead of importing it, all three sections (location, pop, tuition) work... I'm not sure why this is or how to fix it! Sorry for the basic question.

HTML:

```
    <script src="checkbox.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
var allCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
var allPlayers = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.school'));
var checked = {};

getChecked('pop');
getChecked('location');
getChecked('tuition');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(allCheckboxes, function (el) {
  el.addEventListener('change', toggleCheckbox);
});

function toggleCheckbox(e) {
  getChecked(e.target.name);
  setVisibility();
}

function getChecked(name) {
  checked[name] = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[name=' + name + ']:checked')).map(function (el) {
    return el.value;
  });
}

function setVisibility() {
  allPlayers.map(function (el) {
    var pop = checked.pop.length ? _.intersection(Array.from(el.classList), checked.pop).length : true;
    var location = checked.location.length ? _.intersection(Array.from(el.classList), checked.location).length : true;
    var tuition = checked.tuition.length ? _.intersection(Array.from(el.classList), checked.tuition).length : true;
    if (pop && location && tuition) {
      el.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      el.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
}
```

The `tuition` does not change when checkboxes are selected.

Comment: did you try adding defer in you script?  <script src="checkbox.js" defer></script>
this usually makes you script to load once after your HTML is loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the script is loaded at the bottom of your HTML document, or better, use the `defer` attribute so the script wait for the entire HTML to be ready before running.

Having the script being executed too early can make it try to manipulate HTML tags that are not yet ready.

For more information you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24070373/2780319), which explains in details what happens when loading a script within an HTML page.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of including the  tag inside the head or at the starting of body, make sure you include your script in the bottom just above closing the  tag
which should look something like below.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the HTML code?
You could try the following:

1. Make sure you load the JS file as the last element inside the body tag.
2. Try using 'defer' (as suggested above) or 'async' to see if the render cycle corrects and you see the JS in action on the third HTML tuition checkbox as well.